# PySpark s3 Access with Multiple AWS Credential Profiles?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm writing a pyspark job that needs to read out of **two** different s3 buckets. Each bucket has different credentials, which are stored on my machine as separate profiles in `~/.aws/credentials`.

Is there a way to tell pyspark which profile to use when connecting to s3?

When using a single bucket, I had set the `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` environment variables in `conf/spark-env.sh`. Naturally, this only works for accessing 1 of the 2 buckets.

I am aware that I could set these values manually in pyspark when required, using:

```
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", "ABCD")
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey", "EFGH")
```

But would prefer a solution where these values were not hard-coded in. Is that possible?

Answer (score 5):

Different S3 buckets can be accessed with different S3A client configurations. This allows for different endpoints, data read and write strategies, as well as login details.

1. All fs.s3a options other than a small set of unmodifiable values (currently fs.s3a.impl) can be set on a per bucket basis.
2. The bucket specific option is set by replacing the fs.s3a. prefix on an option with fs.s3a.bucket.BUCKETNAME., where BUCKETNAME is the name of the bucket.
3. When connecting to a bucket, all options explicitly set will override the base fs.s3a. values.

source http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.0/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html#Configurations_different_S3_buckets

Answer (score 0):

s3n doesn't support the aws credentials stored in `~/.aws/credentials`, you should try to use hadoop 2.7 and the new hadoop s3 impl: `s3a`, it is using aws sdk.

not sure if the current spark release 1.6.1 works well with hadoop 2.7, but spark 2.0 is definitely no problem with hadoop 2.7 and s3a.

for spark 1.6.x, we made some dirty hack, with the s3 driver from EMR... you can take a look this doc: https://github.com/zalando/spark-appliance#emrfs-support

Comment: Am not sure that this answers my question- could you expand/give an example of accessing 2 buckets that have different credentials?

Comment: you could add all of your different credentials as aws profile under `~/.aws/credentials`, then you can switch profiles by changing `AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE` env var in your spark code.

Comment: The s3 clients spark uses don't support accessing different buckets with different credentials. You could cheat by using the s3n client for one set of credentials, s3a for another. There is another strongly deprecated hack of using the username:password in the URL, as in s3n://awsID@escapedkey:bucket/path

Be aware: do that and your AWS secrets will be scattered through your logs